# Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) glht

Tags: r, statistics, tukey

I want to do a Tukey test on my data and found some [code for it](https://astatsa.com/OneWay_Anova_with_TukeyHSD/_Rcode_tutorial/). I took some time to apply it to my data and I got the error above when I got to the glht. I thought maybe I made a typing error with my data so I tested it with the demo data, but I get the same error:

Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
Variable(s) ‘X’ of class ‘character’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’.

This is the demo data:

```
           Y X
1  0.2855104 A
2  0.3385240 A
3  0.0883132 A
4  0.2059308 A
5  0.3632401 A
6  0.5217391 B
7  0.7633588 B
8  0.3254679 B
9  0.4253057 B
10 0.3780718 B
11 0.9891197 C
12 1.1927181 C
13 0.7882883 C
14 0.5491762 C
15 0.5445882 C
16 1.2670565 D
17 1.6253208 D
18 1.2661090 D
19 1.1541876 D
20 1.2684989 D
21 1.0695187 D
```

This is the full code:

```
install.packages("multcomp")
expt1 <- read.table("demo.txt",header=T)
amod <- aov(Y~X,data=expt1)
summary(amod)
library("multcomp")
tmod <- glht(amod,linfct=mcp(X="Tukey"))
```

And this is how it appears in R (after installing the packages):

```
> expt1 <- read.table("demo.txt",header=T)
> amod <- aov(Y~X,data=expt1)
> summary(amod)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
X            3  3.244  1.0815   27.59 9.26e-07 ***
Residuals   17  0.666  0.0392                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> library("multcomp")
Loading required package: mvtnorm
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: TH.data
Loading required package: MASS

Attaching package: ‘TH.data’

The following object is masked from ‘package:MASS’:

    geyser

> tmod <- glht(amod,linfct=mcp(X="Tukey"))
Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
  Variable(s) ‘X’ of class ‘character’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’.
```

I´m a total newbie and I´m completely stumped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, before you fit `amod`, convert `expt1$X` to a factor, `expt1$X <- as.factor(expt1$X)`. `glht()` relies on the levels of the factor to define hypothesis tests

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data$X <- ordered(data$X, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```